# Unity3d C# Adding/Subtracting health using inventory item

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a little problem here that I've been trying to fix for past couple of hours. I'm using Unity 5 and c# to code with.

I have PlayerScript which has health/thirst/hunger values for the player.

I also have another script that works as the inventory. I've added the item "water" which you as a player can consume.

Here's some code for you to understand more:

PlayerScript:

```
public float health = 100f;
public float hunger = 100f;
public float thirst = 100f;
```

Inventory:

```
if (consumeEffects[i] == "DrinkItem")
                    {
                        GameObject.Find ("FPSController").GetComponent<PlayerScript>().thirst += 25.0f;
                        Debug.Log("You drank some water!");
                    }
```

So basically, I have an item that has Consume category and DrinkItem element ~ which means that when I try to consume for example: water, it should add 25 water to the thirst. But it doesnt!

I know it works because I can see the debug message, but at the same time I get an error:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UI_Hotbar.ActivateItem (Int32 index) (at Assets/UI_Hotbar.cs:120)

Line 120 includes the line where we add 25 to the thirst. Trying to see whats wrong with the UI hotbar in hierarchy doesn't give me answers. Everything looks just fine.

Someone please help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Hierarchy tab?

Comment: @Programmer - there you go: https://i.snag.gy/Q0cSuR.jpg

Comment: Ok FPSController exist. Can you select it and post a picture of components attached to it? At the-same time please include your code to show how `consumeEffects` is initialized.

Comment: @Programmer, here's a piece of a code for consumeEffects: http://pastebin.com/VuukFvAn (it's all works with other items as far as consuming goes, just not with drinking water).

And what do you mean post pictures of components attached to it? Like water? There: https://i.gyazo.com/3ae8c0c77d449014c893e9c4dd8554cd.png

Comment: Close but select `FPSController` GameOBject and post the picture like you  did. Right now you selected the `Water Item` GameObject. I also think you should double click on the error, it will open up the code editor and point to where the error is. Please post that line of code the error is occurring at.

Comment: @Programmer the error points to the exact code I've included earlier, where I find FPSController and then try changing thirst values by adding 25 to it. That's about it. Does that line of a code look right to you?

Comment: GameObject.Find ("FPSController").GetComponent<PlayerScript>().thirst += 25.0f;

Comment: Ok just making sure. Can you do what I said last time?  Select FPSController GameOBject and post the picture like you did. Right now you selected the Water Item GameObject

Comment: My fps controller has a lot to it. But it points me to the inventory system.
https://i.snag.gy/v9UNya.jpg

Comment: The problem is that your FPSController doesn't have a "PlayerScript", but rather has a "First Person Controller".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Image upload in your comment section,`PlayerScript` is not attached your *FPSController* GameObject. That's why `GetComponent<PlayerScript>()` is failing. You must attach `PlayerScript` script to your *FPSController* GameObject.

You can either do that from the Editor or through script in the `Start()` function `GameObject.Find("FPSController").AddComponent<PlayerScript>();`

Comment: Oh my f*cking god! I can't believe this! lol. I had PlayerScript on FirstPersonController rather than FPSController game object. I've changed "FPSController" to "FirstPersonController" and now it all works. Holy shit, thank you very much! I feel so stupid now, lol

Comment: It happens a-lot. It could be GameObject.Find or GetComponent failing. That's why I asked for pictures to verify this.